# What is the subject in "There is no form to reject"?

Tags: grammar, subjects, active-voice

What is the subject in this sentence?

> There is no form to reject.

And what type of sentence is this?

Comment: _No form_ is your subject (it's a **dummy there**).

Comment: This kind of question is more appropriate for [ell.se]. Also, when you ask it there, you should add a lot more detail especially what you already know about things, what you think the subject is (or why it is hard to figure out what it is for you).

Comment: The sentence is seen as being derived from 'No form is to reject' (think 'No form exists to reject') where 'No form' is clearly the subject. Most analysts see it better to retain 'no form' as being the subject even when the form of the rephrase, using existential 'there' as a 'dummy subject' (English often prefers to shift weight towards the back of a sentence), would suggest otherwise.

Comment: But there are other tests for subjecthood that  _there_ passes and the extraposed NP doesn't. Subject-Raising, for instance. _There_-insertion is a complex case and should have an answer here.  For instance, [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299).

Comment: (And, by the way, it should be _the sentence below_, not *_the below sentence_)

Comment: Does this sentence have object

Comment: What does "There is no form to reject" even mean?? This is very idiomatic usage **but** implies something precedes it that explains it, from another speaker. If you are fighting with someone about something, you might say: There is no book, There's only a movie. So, a context here is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

***There*** is an "expletive subject".

It is a bit like the word "it" in the sentence "It is raining". So what is "it"? It is a placeholder with no essential meaning, called an "expletive subject" or "pleonastic subject".

You will find out more about the expletive subject at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining/5763#5763)

Comment: I'm more familiar with the term "dummy subject", but "expletive" checks out. Is that linguistics terminology?

Comment: @gotube Well - I'm certainly no authority on linguistics - I'm just a plain old native speaker. But if you look at the link I included you may find out a lot more.